# C# treeview of one type?

Tags: c#, treeview, treeviewitem

I would like to make a treeview, but as the treeview items type can be anything I always have to make casts. Is there a way to set, like in a list, the only type of the children of a treeview, because that would really make things faster and clearer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so. But casting an object doesn't really slow your application down - it mainly is an information for the compiler that you can use the stuff of the class you parsed the object to. Otherwise I think you could make a new treeView inheriting from the old one. There you could override the paint stuff and use your own custom list of items. I doubt this is worth the effort though.

Comment: Thank you very much